# Conflict between React Native FBSDK, Deep Linking and Redux

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native, redux, deep-linking

I'm currently going through an issue with the React Native FBSDK, Deep Linking and Redux.

I'm supposed to add this code to my existing project because they both use the same method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation

{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

Exisiting code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url


sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url

sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                 annotation:annotation];
}
```

I have found multiple potential fixes as mentioned in this thread:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2359

but none of they work, they all still send me the following error message:

> cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

It seems to be linked to redux and the way we set up the store but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Has anybody gone through a similar problem?

I would greatly appreciate any help on that.